# Silent push notification is making the task running on main thread to stop

Tags: ios, multithreading, apple-push-notifications, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

When i receive a silent push notification on the device. It is blocking the other task running on main thread which is leading to problems for me. My app will be running in background all the time. I also tried using dispatch_async for the other task which is being stopped by silent push then also when the handler method for silent push was hit. It is stopping the normal flow. Is there any solution to this problem. 
Any help will be is greatly appreciated.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ // 1
    if (initListner == NULL) {
        initListner = [[InitializeListeners alloc]init];
    }
    [initListner stopNotifying];
    [initListner startNotifying];
    if (bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
            [self BackgroundtaskInvalidate];

           }];
      }
    });
```

as you can see this when "BackgroundtaskInvalidate" and the silent push notification hits at the same time this problem is occuring

Comment: Can you show some code? Your didReceieveRemoteNotification perhaps?

Comment: You should probably post the code you are using for the notification so people can advise what is being run on the main thread

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm using the didReceiveRemoteNotification. But if i'm doing nothing inside that method then also it is behaving the same. I know i'm not using conventional methods. As i said app will be running in background 24*7. My question is that. Even though i'm using dispatch_async then also didReceieveRemoteNotification is blocking the  normal code flow

Comment: @Mikael please see the above comment.

Comment: @Paulw11 as soon as i receive the silent push it blocks the normal flow and will resume after 30sec.

Comment: if you don't show some code we have no idea. I will tell you though that you cannot guarantee that an app runs in the background 24x7 on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 We can. only thing is it cannot be put into AppStore. I'm using enterprise distribution.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've uploaded the code

Comment: @Mikael i've uploaded the code

Comment: Is this the code from `didReceiveRemoteNotification`?

Comment: @Paulw11 No. As i said even i don't insert any code in there i'm getting problems. This occurs when the silent push fries at the same time as "BackgroundtaskInvalidate" method, Which is a rare  but it does happen sometimes

Comment: Sorry, but this code doesn't show anything much. You are starting some sort of notifying and you start a long running task but don't seem to do anything in that task nor end it.

Comment: @Paulw11 as soon as "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method is hit. irrespective of what i have done when that handler method was hit. It is causing problems.

Comment: anyway, the standard tool to work out where code delays are occurring is the time profile instrument

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly. ok i will try to explain in a simpler way. "BackgroundtaskInvalidate" method is hitting every 3min. and "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is hit every 10min. At some time both "didReceiveRemoteNotification" and "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is getting hit simultaneously. Then the app stops. Thats the problem

Comment: @Paulw11 tried it. Thanks for your patience. Can u get any idea from my above comment? I tried everything for 2days and later posted this question

Comment: Ok but I have no idea what your code is *actually doing*.  All you have shown is a fragment of code out of context with an expiration handler. What does the time profiler show? Make sure you select invert call tree and hide system libraries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75260/discussion-between-avinash-and-paulw11).